# Do I really need Django Rest Framework to develop Restful api with Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am learning Django to develop api, but I find that most of the tutorials on the web are all use Django Rest Framework. Does it really need this framework to develop restful apis? Can I develop restful apis without Django Rest Framework

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can develop a rest API without DRF - a rest API is just a set of urls mapped to views that take HTTP requests and return HTTP responses, period. Now since most often "rest API" implies JSON as the default input and output format and a proper use of HTTP verbs, some specific kind of auth etc there are some repetitive tasks that can be factored out - either rolling your own mini-framework, using an existing lightweight one like [restless](https://restless.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), or trying to find your way in the 800-pound gorilla DRF.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can but why, when Django Rest Framework does the work for you ? If you wanna learn how it's working just use Django Rest Framework and watch the sources code of it.

Comment: Yes, I see, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can develop REST API with django, Django Rest Framework isn't part of Django project its a third party tool which facilitate faster API development. DRF takes care of lot of stuff which you need to take care by your own otherwise like.

- Handling token
- Authorization
- Authentication
- Serialization & Deserialization of dataobject
- likewise many other.